# Is there a way to lint only modified part in a .js file before git commit?

Tags: javascript, git, eslint, gjslint

I will maintain a old project and I must check self commited code with some lint tool, such as eslint or gjslint.

If simply run gjslint or eslint for a .js file, I will get all the lint error...

I don't want to chang the old part which no bug with it.

So is there a way to run gjslint or eslint only for modified part in a .js file before git commit?

Thanks.